# Android OpenGL 2D rotation not working at all

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to get a simple 2d openGL game started. I'm having trouble with rotation though. Both rotation and translation don't seem to work. I get no results at all.
In the example below, I'm trying to rotate a small 50x50 square in the center of the screen.

---

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    gl10.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    gl10.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    textures = new int[1];

    // LOAD TEXTURE
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.grass);

    gl10.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl10.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    gl10.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl10.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    mCrop = new int[4];
    mCrop[0] = 0;
    mCrop[1] = bitmap.getHeight();
    mCrop[2] = bitmap.getWidth();
    mCrop[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    bitmap.recycle();
}




 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glOrthof(0.0f, sWidth, 0.0f, sHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        ((GL11)gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCrop, 0);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(anglefromcenter, 0, 1, 0);
        ((GL11Ext)gl).glDrawTexfOES(sWidth/2, sHeight/2, 0, 50, 50);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

    ...
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this will help at all, but you may want to maybe try glOrtho2D instead of glOrthf? Just an idea? I am by far no expert! I will give you code a shot though.

Comment: Do you load Identity into modelview at some point in you initialization?  You don't have to do it every draw call, just at some point before starting to draw.  Also is anglefromcenter incrimenting when you debug?

Comment: my GL object seems to only have glOrthf and glOrthox?

Comment: I've tried switching to the modelview state and using loadidentity in many different places. I posted more of my code just now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not sure it "glDrawTexfOES" can be used with any matrix at all. As for "glRotatef" what you did would only appear to scale the image around X as if glScalef(sin(anglefromcenter), 1.0, 1.0). Also note that glRotatef has angle in degrees.

Comment: I tried many variations of glRotatef not just that one. Do you think there is ANY way to rotate at all, if I can't use glRotatef?

Comment: Use vertices and texture coordinates